# std::none_of example from cppreference.com

Tags: c++

Can anyone help me understand this example:

v is a std::vector here. I think that std::bind here is binding what's in it to the function std::none_of as it's the condition. std::modulus is taking mod of the two parameters. But why is their _1 and 2 without the underscore.

```
if (std::none_of(v.cbegin(),
                 v.cend(),
                 std::bind(std::modulus<int>(), std::placeholders::_1, 2))) {
        std::cout << "None of them are odd\n";
}
```

Comment: `_1` is the bound parameter (ie the value of each element of the vector).  `2` (without the _) is the modulus value.

Answer (score 2):

`std::modulus<int>()` is a function object that takes two arguments.

`std::bind(std::modulus<int>(), std::placeholders::_1, 2)` creates a function object that takes *one* argument. It takes one argument because it has a single placeholder. The second argument to `std::modulus<int>()` is bound to the number `2`.

Then `none_of` is called over the range of `v` using this new unary function object, calling it on each item in the vector. So basically it is checking `x % 2` for each element `x` in `v`.